# Combining Data Sources/Persistence in SwiftUI Options/Best Practices?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swiftui

I am newish to Swift/SwiftUI and have been reading a ton of resources. Using what I am learning along with another example app similar to what I am trying to create, I am making an app that downloads a JSON file from an external API service. That JSON data contains the main part of my code (items from a video game), and my app displays that data in various views. My question though is this: I want a user to be able to track a few things about each object, such as whether they have collected it. I have spent 2-3 weeks researching and trying various options of how to do this, but I am wondering what the most efficient/most popular way of doing something like this is in real-world apps?

Here are some things I have been considering:

- Download the API JSON initially and then create both it and my collection data as one object. From there, I would persist that data either be encoding back to a JSON file to be stored in the app's documents directory or in Core Data (or even Realm). The views would actually pull from my own personal data. My first concern with this method is that the API JSON may have changes at some point and I would like the app to always have the most up-to-date version of that info (and I don't know how to compare for updated info yet). My second concern is why keep all of that extra info locally in my app when someone else is already hosting it (or should I do that anyway so the app can be used offline)? If that is the case, is there a tutorial or something around that shows how to manage downloaded JSON data without completely overwriting current data?
- Download the API JSON as I currently am (every time a view needs it), and store the collection info as its own data. This is the method I think makes more sense, but my question is how do I combine it with the API JSON? Is it easiest to use JSON or Core Data to combine these files? Do I use the Combine framework? Are there other frameworks/methods that would be better suited for that?

To sum up:
My app downloads JSON files from an API containing items from a game that can be collected. I want the user to be able to track whether they have collected said items from that game. I don't know the best way to do this or what framework/classes I should be researching to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is considered "opinion-based" any more so than any other question ever posted to this site. I asked a legitimate question about an advanced topic of app-making that I have not been able to find an answer for, and it is no more "opinion-based" than asking how to loop through an array and getting 4-5 different possible answers of people's "opinions" on the best way to do that. I spent a lot of time trying to find the answer myself so it was "well-researched."

Comment: SO can be random, with poorly researched questions getting tons of up votes. Keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Most tutorials for CoreData and SwiftUI, FYI, both ignore MVVM (e.g., using @FetchRequest so your view directly reads your model) and the benefits of abstracting your persistence choice with a DataManager object and protocol. Doing the latter lets you choose CoreData now and switch to Google Firebase later (i.e., launching a collaborative Android version), without changing any View code or really any ViewModel code. You can follow the same principles with JSON decoding as just a different DataManger for initializing data for your ViewModel to apportion to views. Ok, done with soap box.

If your dataset is really big and you plan to query it sideways, CoreData may be nice. Or just a skill to learn. It's not that bad.

But if the use case is something simple like

- Character 1
  -- isStarredAsAwesome
  -- copiesCollected
  -- maxLevelofCopyCollected
  -- dateCollected

Then just save JSON to the Bundle.

The benefit of CoreData is you could query relationships, such as get a brag sheet of which of my video game characters are in my friends library, but at a higher level and played for fewer hours but collected far in the past. In a large dataset, CoreData will be faster than looping over arrays yourself. But for a smaller dataset like yours may be, again, it may not matter really at all.

I'm building a note-taking app with lots of cross-ways uses of entered text. In this case, CoreData was easier than managing all those relationships in JSON, which makes the extra function calls to manage CoreData CRUD calls worth it.

Also, you may want to ship the JSON with your app and then call an updater on launch. This way, in case the API changes, your app isn't immediately broken until you get around to updating it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So would I ship the JSON, load it into Core Data on app launch, then query Core Data directly? Then in subsequent launches, call the updater to download a fresh JSON and compare/update the Core Data?

Comment: Yeah that's one way. Your save-as-a-file way works, too. In the learning process (I'm there too, so add salt to my suggestions) I think it's fair to take whatever route will give you skills that you plan to apply to your next project, but not take on too much at once that you get distracted and just start the next project when you hit an inspiration speed bump. :)

Comment: Ok, re-reading your answer from last night, I understand a little better now. So I do think it is pretty simple and doesn't really *need* Core Data per say as there would never really be the need for advanced queries. So instead I think it would be more like: ship JSON, on app launch, query for new JSON and update if necessary, and query the shipped/permanent JSON for views? If that is correct, where would I find info on doing those steps. I feel like advanced JSON operation tutorials in Swift are limited. Is that where something like Combine or CombineLatest would come in? Or am I way off?

Comment: Oh, and would Core Data be overkill if that is all I am looking for in data persistence? Or could it be good practice to use it?

Comment: I don't have a specific JSON tutorial in my notes, but you could look at Azam Sharp and his Udemy course ($15) or AppCoda (more expensive book, but good). Combine is good for managing async state, yes, and it's actually not that hard to do the basics. At the first the terminology made me delay learning, but AppCoda Mastering SwiftUI Chapter 14 and 15 explains it pretty well, particularly for your use cases. Chapter 21 is on JSON.

Comment: The choice, given the learning context, is less about your app now and more about your next few apps. Do you want to create your own file formats? JSON decoding/coding is good to know then. Do you plan on making more and more advanced databases? Then learn CoreData in a simple use case first. The right answer isn't about your project, but you. Later on, the right answer becomes about the time you're willing to dedicate to a project. :)